# React StrictMode doubles array items

Tags: reactjs

I know that StrictMode logs things twice and everything but before now it never did such thing as changing the value of an array or variable. Without strict mode data state has 25 items as it should, with StrictMode it has 50, duplicates of first 25

my custom hook code

```
    const useRequest = (page) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [error, setError] = useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
        const url = `someURL/{page}/25` <-- number of items to fetch
        setLoading(true)
        setError('')

        fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setData(prev => [...prev, ...data.items])
        })

        setLoading(false)


    },[page])

    return { loading, data, error}
}
```

app.js code

```
const App = () => {
  const [pageNumber,setPageNumber] = useState(1)
  const { loading, data, error } = useRequest(pageNumber)

  console.log(data)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <main>
        {data.map((user,id) => 
          <Card 
            key={id} 
            userData={user}
          />
        )}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `setData(data.items)`?

Comment: I need it that way, to add other items when the user scrolls further down

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/18

```
const useRequest = (page) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const loadedRef = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loadedRef.current) return;
    loadedRef.current = true;
    const url = `someURL/{page}/25`; // <-- number of items to fetch
    setLoading(true);
    setError("");

    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setData((prev) => [...prev, ...data.items]));

    setLoading(false);
  }, [page]);

  return { loading, data, error };
};
```